# Setting array of objects using map returns same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array

```
listItems 
0: "/static/media/m1.895f1b11.jpg"
​​1: "/static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg"
length: 2
```

And a Object

```
item={
  src: "", 
  key: ""
}
```

I`m trying to add each listItems to src in item like :

```
item={
  src: "/static/media/m1.895f1b11.jpg", 
  key: 0
}
```

and this item into items :

```
//before :
items = [];
```

```
//after (this is what I want) :
items = [
  {
  src: "/static/media/m1.895f1b11.jpg", 
  key: 0
},
{
  src: "/static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg", 
  key: 1
}
];
```

to do this, I use the map in listItems and for each item I add it to src of my item object
and then I add my item object to my array of objects items

```
listItems.map( (img,index) => {
                    item.src = img;
                    item.key = index;
                    console.log("item.src : " +item.src + " item.key : "+item.key + " img : "+img + " index "+ index);
                    items.push(item);
                });
                for(k=0;k<items2.length;k++)
                console.log("items["+k+"] : "+items[k].src);
```

It looks fine, but when i get my log results :

```
item.src : /static/media/m1.895f1b11.jpg item.key : 0 img : /static/media/m1.895f1b11.jpg index 0 
item.src : /static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg item.key : 1 img : /static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg index 1 
items[0] : /static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg 
items[1] : /static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg
```

Booth items[0] and items[1] are the same,where is the problem?

Comment: Where are you creating a new item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you only have *one* `item` object, which you just modify in the loop. Realise that even when you have pushed `item` in an array, this doesn't mean you cannot still mutate it. And that you do (in the next iteration of the loop), and then you push `item` again, so your array has now two references to the same object (in its latest state).

A side note: `.map` is intended to return an array. Use that power.

```
let items = listItems.map((img, index) => {
    return { // a NEW object
        src: img,
        key: index
    };
});
```

Or even shorter, by using smart names for your variables, and the arrow-function-expression syntax:

```
let items = listItems.map((src, key) => ({src, key}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're operating on the same object instance. With `item.src = img` you're just updating the `src` property of the same object instance, therefore you get the same object inside the array 2 times.

You need to create new object instances for each item:

```
const items = listItems.map((src, index) => ({
  key: index,
  src,
}));
```

The `... => ({ ... })` creates a new object instance for each item, it can also written like:

```
const items = listItems.map((src, index) => {
  return {
    key: index,
    src,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this

```
const listItems = ["/static/media/m1.895f1b11.jpg", "/static/media/m2.895f1b11.jpg"]

const list = []

listItems.map((item, index) => {
        let newObj = {}
    newObj.src = item;
    newObj.key = index;
    list.push(newObj);
}   )

console.log(list)
```

create each object inside the map and push that object to the array.

Comment: If you're going to use `.map()`, then you should use it as it's intended to be used. Right now you're building and discarding an extra array filled with `undefined`.